# Converting string format to datetime in mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to convert string in mm/dd/yyyy format to datetime variable but it should remain in mm/dd/yyyy format.

```
string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Please help.

Comment: The datetime variable doesnt have a format internally.

Comment: _"but it should remain in mm/dd/yyyy format"_ then you're talking about a string, you can use `DateTime.ToShortDateString`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are looking for the `DateTime.Parse()` method ([MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx))

So you can do:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2001");
```

Which will give you a `DateTime` typed object.

If you need to specify which date format you want to use, you would use `DateTime.ParseExact` ([MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx))

Which you would use in a situation like this (Where you are using a British style date format):

```
string[] formats= { "dd/MM/yyyy" }
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/2001", formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: You do not need an array of `formats` when you have only one format string to consider; there are other overloads of `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 36):

**You need an uppercase `M` for the month part.**

```
string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Lowercase `m` is for outputting (and parsing) a minute (such as `h:mm`).

e.g. a full date time string might look like this:

```
string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm");
```

Notice the uppercase/lowercase `mM` difference.

---

Also if you will always deal with the same datetime format string, you can make it easier by writing them as C# extension methods.

```
public static class DateTimeMyFormatExtensions
{
  public static string ToMyFormatString(this DateTime dt)
  {
    return dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
  }
}

public static class StringMyDateTimeFormatExtension
{
  public static DateTime ParseMyFormatDateTime(this string s)
  {
    var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    return DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
  }
}
```

---

**EXAMPLE:** Translating between DateTime/string

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

string strNow = now.ToMyFormatString();
DateTime nowAgain = strNow.ParseMyFormatDateTime();
```

Note that there is *NO* way to store a custom `DateTime` format information to use as `default` as in .NET most string formatting depends on the currently set culture, i.e.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.
```

The only easy way you can do is to roll a custom extension method.

Also, the other easy way would be to use a different "container" or "wrapper" class for your DateTime, i.e. some special class with `explicit operator` defined that automatically translates to and from DateTime/string. But that is dangerous territory.

Comment: I did this..now i want to store it as datetime variable.

Comment: @aviral see https://gist.github.com/2319253 for example. But please try to understand all the pieces before using it.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

I did like this

```
var datetoEnter= DateTime.ParseExact(createdDate, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: your format is **wrong**.. "dd/MM/yyyy" the capital makes a different... otherwise you are putting minutes into the Date.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the format too by doing this

```
string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString(format:"dd-MM-yyyy");
```

// this change the `"/"` for the `"-"`

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

```
string strToday = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```