# Convert computer datetime format into mm/dd/yyyy format in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to Convert PC datetime format to MM/DD/YYYY type using C#. I have 05-feb-2014 or like that type format. Please help..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043022/converting-string-format-to-datetime-in-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: Are you sure you want that format hard-coded? USA is in the minority, most countries do not use MMDDYY. Please say whether you want it hard-coded, or whether you want a format that depends on your regional settings.

Comment: This type format is showing like one user PC. I want to convert that format... if hardcoded or how ever please add comment...