# How do I convert a string value of date like Mon, 5/5/2014 to datetime dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Right now I'm using the method stated below and it displays the result in this manner `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

```
string date = "Mon, 15/05/2014";
DateTime alertedDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(date, new string[] { "ddd, dd/MM/yyyy" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out alertedDate);
txtDate.Text = Convert.ToString(alertedDate);
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Also, my database date value stores the data in `MM/dd/YYYY` format and my `Globalization.CultureInfo` is in UK format which is `dd/MM/yyyy`.  Could this cause the error

Comment: What's the error message you getting?

Comment: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
string date = "Thu, 15/05/2014";
```

15/5/2014 is Thursday.

Comment: This is the correct answer. A try-parse method will deliver the default value of `DateTime`, which is 0001, January 1, when the string cannot be parsed into a valid date-and-time. The reason why it happens here is that 2014, May 15 is no Monday. The asker should strongly consider picking up the boolean returned by the `TryParseExact` method to check if the parse was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] formats= { "dd/MM/yyyy" };
string date = "Mon, 15/05/2014";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Reference: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043022/converting-string-format-to-datetime-in-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: Have you tried your own code? It gives a `FormatException` at run-time. Not surpising, for the part `"Mon, "` does not match the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
txtDate.Text = alertedDate.ToString("s")
```