# Bootstrap datepicker. Trouble binding: The value is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm having trouble binding a property of my model using bootstrap datepicker. I'm getting the following error:

[image]

*The value DATE is not valid for DATEFIELD*

This is how the property is defined in my model:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaDesignado { get; set; }
```

This is how the view is constructed:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <input type="datetime" class="datepicker form-control" asp-for="@item.FechaDesignado"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="@item.FechaDesignado" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which translates to:

```
<div class="form-group" form="form1">
    <div>
        <input type="datetime" class="datepicker form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FechaDesignado field is required." name="item.FechaDesignado" value="09/01/1901" />
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.FechaDesignado" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks on my DB.

[image]

This is the code for datepicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            "autoclose": true
        });
    });

</script>
```

Post Action inside the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Management")]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Management(int? id)
    {
        var storetoupdate = _context.Stores.SingleOrDefault(m => m.StoreID == id.Value);
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            storetoupdate, "item",
            s => s.StoreName, s => s.IncomePeriodicity, s=>s.Usuario, s => s.FechaDesignado))
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Management");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Management");
    }
```

**Question:** Seems like I must convert the date input field to a datetime object using `DateTime.ParseExact` but I don't know how to edit the controller for this. Sorry but I'm learning all this.

Thanks.

Comment: Ideally, you do not need to manually bind the date value to the view model. Is the post date value not bind to Store View Model's FechaDesignado property correctly?

Comment: @Win yeap, the property FechaDesignado of the Store model is not binding to the model, saying that the value sent it's not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` for convert `date` format to `datetime`. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043022/converting-string-format-to-datetime-in-mm-dd-yyyy) for more information.

**Edit**

You can use `data-format` attribute like this for post correct format date:

```
<input data-format="0:MM/dd/yyyy" type="datetime" class="datepicker form-control" asp-for="@item.FechaDesignado"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm investigating about this but I wonder how to introduce it inside my post action :(

Comment: @LuisAlbertoDelgadodelaFlo I edited my answer please see again. I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :)